# How do I open a pre-existing .NET Core application in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

As the title suggests, I'm simply looking to open the directory that has my .NET Core application (I bootstrapped the application from the `dotnet` CLI tool with the command `dotnet new -t web`).

It seems that I can only open a Solution file rather than just a directory. How would I then generate a Solution, but maintain the development work I've already done in this project?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Solution with a .NET core project template and then copying your files into the new project?

Comment: @alexw I have. What ends up happening is 1. Visual Studio doesn't show any of the files like README.md and project.json, it just shows directories and 2. when you attempt to build the project there are ~250 errors (even after entering the /src/[projectName] directory and running `dotnet restore` in it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to upgrade to latest SDK at http://dot.net (preview >= 3), and migrate existing project.json based projects using `dotnet migrate`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/dotnet-migrate

Then the csproj files can be opened in VS for Mac.

Comment: Just to add to what Lex Li has written. The new Sdk style project format currently generated by dotnet 1.0 preview 5 is not yet supported in Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: @MattWard thanks. I didn't realize preview 5 is out. It's too swift.